# Loop colours from variables for graphics.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a graphics program that draws 100 x 100 squares next to each other depending on the user-specified grid size. The user also inputs 4 colours for the squares to be coloured (e.g. if they enter red,green,blue,yellow the squares will be coloured in that order, repeating the colours).

Is it possible to loop the colours from the variables the user has given?

Here is what I have so far:

```
def main():
    print ("Please enter four comma seperated colours e.g.: 'red,green,blue,yellow'\n\
    Allowed colours are: red, green, blue, yellow and cyan")
    col1, col2, col3, col4 = input("Enter your four colours: ").split(',')
    win = GraphWin ("Squares", 500, 500)
    colours = [col1, col2, col3, col4]
    drawSquare (win, col1, col2, col3, col4, colours)
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()


def drawSquare(win, col1, col2, col3, col4, colours):
    for i in range (4):
        for j in range (len(colours)):
            colour = colours[j]
            x = 50 + (i * 50)
            circle = Circle (Point (x,50), 20)
            circle.setFill(colour)
            circle.draw(win)
```

I think I should be using a list in some way, but can't work out exactly how to do it.

Comment: Your drawSquare function is using class Circle ? Is not that a constraint ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select 4 colors given a user variable you can use modulus.

```
color_index = user_var % 4
```

then you can get your color as:

```
mycolor = colours[color_index]
```

Alternatively, if you want to give a different color each time a user need it and cycle on them when the available colors are exhausted you can use itertools.cycle iterator:

```
In [21]: colours = ['r','b','y','c']
In [22]: from itertools import cycle
In [23]: color = cycle(colours)

In [25]: color.next()
Out[25]: 'r'

In [27]: color.next()
Out[27]: 'b'

In [28]: color.next()
Out[28]: 'y'

In [29]: color.next()
Out[29]: 'c'

In [30]: color.next()
Out[30]: 'r'

In [31]: color.next()
Out[31]: 'b'
```

In this way you can get:

[image]

and the code:

```
from graphics import GraphWin, Rectangle, Point
from itertools import cycle

def main():
    print (("Please enter four comma seperated colours e.g.:"
             "'red,green,blue'\n" 
             "Allowed colours are: red, green, blue, yellow and cyan"))
    colours = input("Enter your four colours: ").split(',')
    print ("Please enter gridsize e.g.: '100'")
    gsize = int(input("Enter gridsize: "))
    win_size = 250
    win = GraphWin("Squares", win_size, win_size)
    drawSquares(win, gsize, win_size, colours)
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

def drawSquares(win, gsize, winsize, colours):
    side = winsize / gsize
    color = cycle(colours)
    for row in range(gsize):
        y1 = row * side
        y2 = y1 + side
        for column in range(gsize):
            x1 = column * side
            x2 = x1 + side
            rect = Rectangle(Point(x1, y1), Point(x2, y2))
            rect.setFill(color.next())
            rect.draw(win)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your question is, but you cal variable col1-col4 that you never actually use. Also, looping over range(len(iterable)) is silly. Here is a simplified version.

```
def main():
    print ("Please enter four comma seperated colours e.g.: 'red,green,blue,yellow'\n\
    Allowed colours are: red, green, blue, yellow and cyan")
    colours = input("Enter your four colours: ").split(',')
    win = GraphWin ("Squares", 500, 500)
    drawSquare (win, colours)
    win.getMouse()
    win.close()


def drawSquare(win, colours):
    for i in range (4):
        for colour in colours:
            x = 50 + (i * 50)
            circle = Circle (Point (x,50), 20)
            circle.setFill(colour)
            circle.draw(win)
```

"Is it possible to loop the colours from the variables the user has given?"

Yes. You are doing that already.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out I was creating variables I wasn't using. If i wanted to loop the circle more than 4 times, is it possible to simply start at the beginning of the list again? e.g. the fifth circle would start at the first colour entered?

Comment: @user1056548 You are currently looping over all colors 4 times.  To change that, simply change the `4` in `for i in range (4)` (Make it user input or dependent on screen/grid size perhaps?).